# Add a .pem to Heroku SSL Endpoint

Tags: heroku, pem, lets-encrypt

I used [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate a .pem. I need to add this to [Heroku SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) but it fails when I try:

```
sudo heroku _certs:add /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mysite.com/fullchain.crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mysite.com/fullchain.key
  # ENOENT: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...'
OR
sudo heroku _certs:add /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mysite.com/fullchain.pem
  # Missing argument: KEY
```

How can I add the .pem to SSL Endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the SSL certificate (including the chain) and the key.

The extension of the files is irrelevant. Generally, a certificate is saved in a .pem or .crt file, a key in a .key file.

The first line is correct, but it's like either the first or the second file paths are incorrect.

The second line is failing because you only supplied one argument (the certificate) and not the key.

Make sure that:

1. both arguments are supplied
2. both arguments are valid file paths pointing to existing files

Comment: Hi Simone. The folder Let's Encrypt created in my hard drive contains the following files: cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem, and privkey.pem. I don't know where the .key is.

Comment: `privkey.pem` is the private key.